# Access a text area behind a jQuery UI modal dialog

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I am using a modal dialog to popup on a page that requires the user to enter some information to continue. Obviously, the modal property disables all the other controls on the page behind the faded div, which is what we want. In this case however, there is a "notes" field that must always be able to be typed into - even if the dialog is showing. In the actual application, it's a slide out panel, but here is a fiddle for trying to access a second text area on a page behind the modal popup:

HTML:

```
<div id="modal-dialog">
    <textarea id="my-text"></textarea>
</div>
<label for="my-text2">TRY to input text...</label>
<textarea id="my-text2" style="position:relative; z-index:10000"></textarea>
```

Javascript:

```
$("#modal-dialog").dialog({
    autoOpen: true,
    modal: true,
    _allowInteraction: function (event) {
        alert('test');
        return !!$(event.target).is("#my-text2") || this._super(event);
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6bhdpg12/

Is there any way to get the text area "my-text2" to be editable? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

By setting `modal: false`, the popup will no longer act like a modal and you will be able to interact with other elements on the page.

If you want to keep some of the effects of the modal window and want to implement an override, you will need to create a widget. Make sure this is placed ahead of your modal jQuery:

```
$.widget( "ui.dialog", $.ui.dialog, {
    _allowInteraction: function (event) {
        return !!$(event.target).is("#my-text2") || this._super(event);
    }
});
```

You would then keep your existing modal window jQuery:

```
$("#modal-dialog").dialog({
    autoOpen: true,
    modal: true,
});
```

I forked your fiddle and updated it here: http://jsfiddle.net/mdeang2/yq5et92g/1/

Comment: Correct, but there are a whole bunch of other controls on the page that I'd like to be disabled, as well as the visual effect of the "mask/overlay" div that fades out the page. Is there a way to select a particular control or div and have it excluded from the modal behaviour?